# How to use count and group by at the same select statement

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have an SQL `SELECT` query that also uses a `GROUP BY`,
I want to count all the records after the `GROUP BY` clause filtered the resultset.

Is there any way to do this directly with SQL? For example, if I have the table `users` and want to select the different towns and the **total** number of users:

```sql
SELECT `town`, COUNT(*)
FROM `user`
GROUP BY  `town`;
```

I want to have a column with all the towns and another with the number of users in all rows.

An example of the result for having 3 towns and 58 users in total is:

| Town | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Copenhagen | 58 |
| New York | 58 |
| Athens | 58 |

Comment: you mean you want your result set to have 2 counts one for towns and one for users?

Comment: So you want one row for each town, and in each row, column 2 contains the total count of all users? So column 2 has the *same* value for each row? If you edit to include sample data and required output we will be able to give you exactly what you want.

Comment: You are right AakashM! I just edited it.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146978/count-number-of-records-returned-by-group-by

Comment: _Caveat to readers: Most of the answers fail to provide an answer for the query as updated._

Comment: Isn't your query correct?

Answer (score 343, accepted):

This will do what you want *(list of towns, with the number of users in each)*:

```sql
SELECT `town`, COUNT(`town`)
FROM `user`
GROUP BY `town`;
```

You can use most [aggregate functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) when using a `GROUP BY` statement
(`COUNT`, `MAX`, `COUNT DISTINCT` etc.)

**Update:**
You can declare a variable for the number of users and save the result there, and then `SELECT` the value of the variable:

```sql
DECLARE @numOfUsers INT
SET @numOfUsers = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user`;

SELECT DISTINCT `town`, @numOfUsers FROM `user`;
```

Answer (score 194):

You can use [`COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count-distinct) :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT town) 
FROM user
```

Comment: I think they mean if you put COUNT(DISTINCT town) in the WHERE clause. That is because it is an aggregate function and needs to be provided in the HAVING clause. This SQL query is misleading to some as SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT town) turns into an implicit GROUP BY, due to both the COUNT and DISTINCT keywords, each keyword on their own would also implicitly group.

Comment: Thanks. Upvote. Exactly what is needed - group + count in one op and get a single row in result.

Comment: Shit.. I didn't know that was possible!

Comment: You have my respect master! Thank you very much. Such simple solution.

Comment: Is performing slow when use DISTINCT

Comment: That query comes back with simply "3", not a list of the 3 towns, nor the total user count.

Comment: @RickJames right, I have deleted that answer. You can use the solution from "Oded" or "Violendy Firdaus".

Comment: @milkovsky - Thanks for deleting that wrong answer.  I am on a campaign to get rid of the rest of the "wrong answers".  _This_ answer is still wrong -- the OP is asking for 2 columns; your query gives only one.

Comment: @RickJames I agree, this answer does not exactly fit to the required results. Quite some people found it useful though. I could change this answer, but other answers already contain correct queries. Do I have to delete it?

Comment: @milkovsky - No you don't have to delete it.  I just find it irritation that this Question plus the many Answers have bifurcated into solving two _different_ problems.  Your answer deviates in two ways -- no `town` column, and it `COUNTs` the wrong thing (town instead of user).

Comment: Showing the output would be nice, so we know better what problem this solves.

Comment: Doesn't work with `group by` style queries :|

Comment: @rogerdpack `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` does work with `GROUP BY`, just make sure your grouping field is present in the `SELECT` statement.
Example: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT town), street FROM user GROUP BY street`

Answer (score 46):

The other way is:

```
/* Number of rows in a derived table called d1. */
select count(*) from
(
  /* Number of times each town appears in user. */
  select town, count(*)
  from user
  group by town
) d1
```

Comment: needs alias otherwise wouldnt work in mysql.
select count(*) from(   ) agr

Answer (score 13):

Ten non-deleted answers; most do *not* do what the user asked for.  Most Answers mis-read the question as thinking that there are 58 users in *each* town instead of 58 in total.  Even the few that are correct are not optimal.

```
mysql> flush status;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT  province, total_cities
    FROM       ( SELECT  DISTINCT province  FROM  canada ) AS provinces
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT  COUNT(*) total_cities  FROM  canada ) AS tot;
+---------------------------+--------------+
| province                  | total_cities |
+---------------------------+--------------+
| Alberta                   |         5484 |
| British Columbia          |         5484 |
| Manitoba                  |         5484 |
| New Brunswick             |         5484 |
| Newfoundland and Labrador |         5484 |
| Northwest Territories     |         5484 |
| Nova Scotia               |         5484 |
| Nunavut                   |         5484 |
| Ontario                   |         5484 |
| Prince Edward Island      |         5484 |
| Quebec                    |         5484 |
| Saskatchewan              |         5484 |
| Yukon                     |         5484 |
+---------------------------+--------------+
13 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

`SHOW session status LIKE 'Handler%';`

```
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 4     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 3     |
| Handler_read_key           | 16    |
| Handler_read_last          | 1     |
| Handler_read_next          | 5484  |  -- One table scan to get COUNT(*)
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 15    |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 14    |  -- leapfrog through index to find provinces  
+----------------------------+-------+
```

In the OP's context:

```
SELECT  town, total_users
    FROM       ( SELECT  DISTINCT town  FROM  canada ) AS towns
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT  COUNT(*) total_users  FROM  canada ) AS tot;
```

Since there is only one row from `tot`, the `CROSS JOIN` is not as voluminous as it might otherwise be.

The usual pattern is `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(town)`.  The latter implies checking `town` for being not null, which is unnecessary in this context.

Comment: "The usual pattern is COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(town). The latter implies checking town for being not null, which is unnecessary in this context" Thank you for actually mentioning that, was having a tough time figuring the difference!

Comment: @Ayush - You are welcome.  It seems that most users have not yet discovered that subtle distinction.  In some other cases, one wants `COUNT(DISTINCT town)`.

Answer (score 6):

With Oracle you could use analytic functions:

```
select town, count(town), sum(count(town)) over () total_count from user
group by town
```

Your other options is to use a subquery:

```
select town, count(town), (select count(town) from user) as total_count from user
group by town
```

Comment: something like the last one would work, but I wanted to see if there is any other solution..

Comment: And cannot you use the first (analytic function) option? What database platform are you using?

Comment: @Stavros: The last one is slow

Answer (score 4):

If you want to order by count (sound simple but i can`t found an answer on stack of how to do that) you can do:

```
        SELECT town, count(town) as total FROM user
        GROUP BY town ORDER BY total DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use DISTINCT inside the COUNT like what milkovsky said

in my case:

```
select COUNT(distinct user_id) from answers_votes where answer_id in (694,695);
```

This will pull the count of answer votes considered the same user_id as one count

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, in SQL Server:

```
select  isnull(town,'TOTAL') Town, count(*) cnt
from    user
group by town WITH ROLLUP

Town         cnt
Copenhagen   58
NewYork      58
Athens       58
TOTAL        174
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with answering old posts. However, please include an explanation of your code as well as the code itself.

Comment: The MySQL equivalent (`IFNULL` instead of `ISNULL`) leads to different numbers for each town; the user wanted the total.  According to the Question, 58, not 174, is the total.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select town and total user count, you can use this query below:

```
SELECT Town, (SELECT Count(*) FROM User) `Count` FROM user GROUP BY Town;
```

Comment: This assumes (perhaps reasonably) there there are no duplicate "users" in `User`.

Answer (score 1):

if You Want to use Select All Query With Count Option, try this...

```
 select a.*, (Select count(b.name) from table_name as b where Condition) as totCount from table_name  as a where where Condition
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
select ccode, count(empno) 
from company_details 
group by ccode;
```

Comment: we use  this code to find how many total employee for present day calc in  each and every ccode ( company code ) example : count(empno) is 1839 for ccode 1 and count(empno) is 9421 for ccode 47.