# Myth about the behavior of HAVING clause

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, group-by

I am using SQL Server 2005, and I found weird behavior of the `HAVING` clause.

By definition the `HAVING` clause is **supposed** to work on data **after** it has been grouped. However using the `COUNT` function inside a `HAVING` clause is actually applied on data before it is grouped.

What I am missing here??

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @ProductTypeIDsTable TABLE
(
    A INT
)

INSERT INTO @ProductTypeIDsTable(A) VALUES
(10),(12),(12),(9),(9),(9)

DECLARE @IDsTable TABLE
(
    B INT
)

INSERT INTO @IDsTable(B) VALUES
(9),(10),(12)
```

The query in question:

```
SELECT A 
    FROM @ProductTypeIDsTable pt 
    INNER JOIN @IDsTable ids ON pt.A = ids.B
    GROUP BY A
    --HAVING COUNT (A) = 1 -- gives 10 (repeated once due to the join)
    --HAVING COUNT (A) = 2 -- gives 12 (repeated twice due to the join)
    HAVING COUNT (A) = 3 -- gives 9 (repeated thrice due to the join)
```

Comment: I don't get what you say you get. I get one row with the value `9`. Try here. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62661/group-by-having Or perhaps I **do** get the same as you and I just don't understand your question.

Comment: @Mikael I *think* asker means that since each *group* has only one `A`, the `COUNT(A)` for each group should always be 1; therefore the `2` and `3` lines should return no records.

Comment: `count` is an aggregate function that counts the occurrences for one group. In this case with is `3` for the value `9` and the value is the same if you use it in the field list or in the having clause. `having` is filtering rows **after** `group by` but when you do `count` in the having clause it is counting the aggregated rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the aggregate function `count` will not give you different results if you use it in the field list or in the having clause.

A regular group by on `A`:

```
select pt.A, count(*) as C
from @ProductTypeIDsTable pt
  inner join @IDsTable as ids
    on pt.A = ids.B
group by pt.A
```

Result:

```
A           C
----------- -----------
9           3
10          1
12          2
```

If you use `count` in the `having` clause this value is what you are comparing against.

If you are interested in the count of rows returned after `group by` you can put your query in a sub-query like this:

```
select count(*) as C
from
  (
    select pt.A
    from @ProductTypeIDsTable pt
      inner join @IDsTable as ids
        on pt.A = ids.B
    group by pt.A
  ) as T
```

Result:

```
C
-----------
3
```

**Update:**

From [HAVING (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx)

> Specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate.

From [COUNT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

> Returns the number of items in a group.

Comment: Another approach to Count the whole result set.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146978/count-number-of-records-returned-by-group-by