# How to count how many rows inside a "group by" group meets a certain criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, group-by

I have a table I wish to select data from by grouping the data by using a certain key. For each group I would also like to count how many rows belonging to the group meets a certain criteria. Even if 0 row from that group meets the criteria, I still want to return this group and have a "Count" field display that 0 rows meets the criteria. Because of this, I can't simply filter out undesired rows with a "where" clause and simply select the count of the number of elements inside the group.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In the future, this would be a good thing to review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You may be looking for the OVER() clause.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146978/count-number-of-records-returned-by-group-by

Comment: [Aggregate FILTER clause](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.4#Aggregate_FILTER_clause). So your query should be like `select group_field, count(*) filter (where <certain criteria>) from your_table group by group_field;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using [`CASE WHEN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html) (standard ISO SQL syntax) like in this example:

```
SELECT   a.category,
         SUM(CASE WHEN a.is_interesting = 1 THEN 1 END) AS conditional_count,
         COUNT(*) group_count
FROM     a
GROUP BY a.category
```

This will sum up values of 1 and null values (when the condition is false), which comes down to actually counting the records that meet the condition.

This will however return *null* when no records meet the conditions. If you want to have 0 in that case, you can either wrap the `SUM` like this:

```
COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN a.is_interesting = 1 THEN 1 END), 0)
```

or, shorter, use `COUNT` instead of `SUM`:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.is_interesting = 1 THEN 1 END)
```

For `COUNT` it does not matter what value you put in the `THEN` clause, as long as it is not *null*. It will count the instances where the expression is not *null*.

The addition of the `ELSE 0` clause also generally returns 0 with `SUM`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN a.is_interesting = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

There is however one boundary case where that `SUM` will still return *null*. This is when there is no `GROUP BY` clause and no records meet the `WHERE` clause. For instance:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM   a
WHERE  1 = 0
```

will return *null*, while the `COUNT` or `COALESCE` versions will still return 0.

Comment: I believe you need an `else 0` with this approach.  The `sum` of `null` is `null` and I think the OP wants to display 0.

Comment: Was editing my answer while you made the comment. ;-). Note that with `else 0` you still can get *null*, in the extreme case there are no records.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. No records meeting the condition in the entire table or no record meeting the condition in the group? Because if no records meet the condition using the SUM(CASE "condition" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) I get COUNT=0 for the group as should be

Comment: The extreme case is where you would have one single group, and no `GROUP BY`clause, like `SELECT SUM(...) FROM a WHERE ....` and where no records meet the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 1):

You have a condition on which you `GROUP BY`. Simply add a column with a conditional expression that can be summed up:

```
..., SUM(
   CASE WHEN othercondition THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END
) AS MatchingCondition, ...
```

The rows for which the condition is true will yield 1, thereby appearing as a row count in the grouped results. If no rows match, you will get NULL, so you need to wrap the SUM in a COALESCE to reduce it to the desired value of 0.

## Derived trick

This offers a way to group for different conditions. Say that you have three different conditions which are mutually exclusive, and you want to count all three (i.e., in a GROUP BY tuple you have 32 rows of which 10 match condition 1, 6 match condition 2 and 16 match condition 3). If you additionally know that the maximum number of tuples in a group will never exceed N, you can encode the three conditions in a single number:

```
..., SUM(
   CASE WHEN condition1 THEN 1
        WHEN condition2 THEN N
        WHEN condition3 THEN N*N
        WHEN condition4 THEN N*N*N
        ELSE 0 END
) AS MatchingCondition, ...
```

The resulting number modulo N will yield how many rows match condition1. The number divided by N, modulo N will yield matches for condition2. The modulo remainder by N*N will yield matches for condition3, and so on:

```
num1 = result % N
result = (result - num1) / N
num2 = result % N
result = (result - num2) / N
num3 = result % N
...
```

(A further refinement using larger multipliers allows encoding in a single column the result of several *non-mutually exclusive* conditions).

Comment: That form of `if` is a MySQL-ism.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for! You saved me so much time thank you

Comment: Actually, @trincot's answer is the correct one (it considers the NULL case). I sort of shot from the hip :-(

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are going to need two tables.  One that identifies the categories/groups you want to count and the other would be your data table that you count.  Then you can:

```
Select Category.Name, 
    (Select Count(*) 
       from mydatatable 
      where mydatatable.CategoryId = Category.CateogryId) as Count
```

This will give you your zero count as well.