# JOOQ select count distinct from group

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am trying to count the number of records return by a group by select.

This stackoverflow question summarises the different approaches well:

[Count number of records returned by group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146978/count-number-of-records-returned-by-group-by)

I would like to use the solution:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalRecords
FROM table
GROUP BY column
```

How do I turn this into a JOOQ query?

This is how I would do a simple count query in JOOQ:

```java
Record record = jooq.select( TABLE.COLUMN.count() ).from( TABLE).fetchOne();

return record.into( Long.class );
```

Is it possible to express the "DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalRecords" in JOOQ syntax?

James

Answer (score 8):

Write this:

```java
// Assuming this static import
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

int totalRecords =
jooq.selectDistinct(count().over().as("TotalRecords"))
    .from(TABLE)
    .groupBy(TABLE.COLUMN)
    .fetchOneInto(int.class);
```

The methods you were missing were:

- [`DSLContext.selectDistinct()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#selectDistinct-org.jooq.SelectField-)
- [`DSL.count()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#count--)
- [`WindowOverStep.over()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/WindowOverStep.html#over--) (`WindowOverStep` being a supertype of the type returned by `DSL.count()`)