# MySQL query to retrieve maximum number of items within a given time period

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table like attached.

[image]

I want to find the "number of items in a certain month which has maximum entries in the database".

For instance, Jan has 10 entries, Feb has 13 entries, Mar has 8 entries.

I want to find the the number 13 for Feb from the database as it has the max entries. How do I check the time range in the query?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are looking for. Do you mean how many entries are in a given month? If so try this: http://pastebin.com/VZmfmHsU

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? How to use `WHERE` on a `DATETIME` column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use count and group by at the same select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement)

Answer (score 1):

You can group all of your realeasedates by month and year to get a count like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(releasedate) AS month, YEAR(releasedate) as year, count(r_id) AS number
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY YEAR(releasedate), MONTH(releasedate)
ORDER BY YEAR(releasedate), MONTH(releasedate)
```

This'll give you something like this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| month  |  year  | number |
+--------+--------+--------+
|   1    |  2013  |   13   |
|   2    |  2013  |    8   |
```

Then you could select the maximum like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(releasedate) AS month, YEAR(releasedate) as year, count(r_id) AS number
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY YEAR(releasedate), MONTH(releasedate)
ORDER BY count(r_id)
LIMIT 1
```

Which'll give you:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| month  |  year  | number |
+--------+--------+--------+
|   4    |  2013  |   19   |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Which'll represent the highest month

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mytable` WHERE releasedate >= DATE '2013-02-01' AND releasedate <= DATE '2013-02-28'
```

That should work

**EDIT:**

As suggested by lafor...

```
WHERE YEAR(releasedate)=2013 AND MONTH(releasedate)=2
```

should also work

Comment: Another option would be `WHERE YEAR(releasedate)=2013 AND MONTH(releasedate)=2`