# Count number of records based on unique username

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a weird SQL query that I can't seem to figure out.  I have the following schema:

```
username ip
user1 12345
user2 12345
user3 11111
```

I am trying to count the number of user's per ip. So for instance it would report to me

```
11111 1
12345 2
```

I want to also sort this by the least to the most, so that I can see ip 12345 has 2 accounts associated with it and 11111 has 1 account associated with it.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use count and group by at the same select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement)

Comment: if you think a simple counting query is weird, you're in for some major shocks down the road...

Comment: @MarcB thanks i was overthinking this.

Answer (score 3):

Group by the `ip` and add `distinct` to your user count to count only unique names

```
select ip, 
       count(distinct username) as unique_user_count
from your_table
group by ip
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de4f4c/4) exemplifying what you need.

```
SELECT ip, COUNT(username) AS username_count
FROM `sample`
GROUP BY ip
```

`GROUP BY` allows you to summarize the data by `ip`. The `DISTINCT` shouldn't be necessary if the `username` column has the `UNIQUE` constraint defined on it.