# Count number of occurrences of value in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, group-by, count

I have loaded the results of an SQL query into an array. The fields are `ComputerName`, `time_in_days`, `room`, keyed on `ComputerName`.

I would like to find out how many times each `time_in_days` occurrence happens.

Example values of array are:

```
[STU-CZC1087SNC] => Array
    (
        [ComputerName] => STU-CZC1087SNC
        [time_in_days] => 0
        [room] => 4Q08
    )

[STU-CZC02501QT] => Array
    (
        [ComputerName] => STU-CZC02501QT
        [time_in_days] => 12
        [room] => 2R017
    )
```

So I want to know how many computers have `time_in_days = 12`, and how many have `time_in_days = 0` for example.

It will be used to plot a graph.

How do I do / what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, where $input is your array of arrays with the computer data:

```
$result = array();
foreach($input as $computerName => $arr){
  if(!isset($result[ $arr['time_in_days'] ]))
    $result[ $arr['time_in_days'] ] = 0;
  $result[ $arr['time_in_days'] ]++;
}
return $result;
```

The result will be something like:

```
[
  12 => 2, //2 computers have time_in_days of 12
  0 => 1  //1 computer has time_in_days of 0
]
```

Comment: I would recommend an if/else because when your `if` is `true`, you write to `0`  then immediately overwrite to `1`.  More logical to use `if(...){...=1}else{++}`

Comment: I really prefer it this way. It's in my opinion better readable/understandable code: always increment by one. And functionally separated: if its not set, then initialize the value.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = count(
    array_filter(
        $myArray,
        function($value) {
            return $value['time_in_days'] == 12;
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: **+1** Mark.. Took me a lil while to understand :)

Comment: I dont't think this is the generic solution the OP is asking for. This does not work when there are arbitrary numbers in the computer data. Like time_in_days=15 and time_in_days=2 etc etc.

Comment: @MarkBaker Please improve this code-only answer with a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's the working example:

```
<?php

$computerarray = [
'STU-CZC1087SNC' => Array
(
    'ComputerName' => 'STU-CZC1087SNC',
    'time_in_days' => 0,
    'room' => '4Q08'
),

'STU-CZC02501QT' => Array
(
    'ComputerName' => 'STU-CZC02501QT',
    'time_in_days' => 12,
    'room' => '2R017'
),
'STU-CZC02501QF' => Array
(
    'ComputerName' => 'STU-CZC02501QT',
    'time_in_days' => 12,
    'room' => '2R017'
)    
];


$myarray = array();
foreach($computerarray as $key => $val){
    $myarray[] = $val['time_in_days'];
}

echo "<pre>";
$myarray = array_count_values($myarray);
print_r($myarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
$my_arr = Array();
array_walk($arr, function($v) use(&$my_arr) {$my_arr[] = $v['time_in_days'];});
$time_freq = array_count_values($my_arr);
var_dump($time_freq);
/**
  OUTPUT
**/
array
  0 => int 1
  12 => int 2
```

Comment: A short bit of explanation with this code-only answer will benefit future SO readers.

Answer (score 0):

I'll remove my comment on the question that says:

> The best way to do this is to not use php, but sql to `GROUP BY` `time_in_days` and call `COUNT()`. Here's a push in [the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement).

As for a conditional-less, functional approach, here is a one-liner using the two functions that were specifically designed for this task: [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f5f749e8bd11fb95e5d886a61a0bf86112961c82))

```
$computerarray = [
    'STU-CZC1087SNC' => ['ComputerName' => 'STU-CZC1087SNC','time_in_days' => 0,'room' => '4Q08'],
    'STU-CZC02501QT' => ['ComputerName' => 'STU-CZC02501QT','time_in_days' => 12,'room' => '2R017'],
    'STU-CZC02501QF' => ['ComputerName' => 'STU-CZC02501QT','time_in_days' => 12,'room' => '2R017']    
];

var_export(array_count_values(array_column($computerarray,'time_in_days')));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  12 => 2,
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe array_count_values, see manual:
https://www.php.net/array_count_values

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($ya as $a) {
    $newarr[$a['time_in_days']]++;
}
```

Comment: Almost the same as my answer, you will get lot's of notices with this code. Just add error_reporting(0); to prevent those? ;-P

Answer (score -1):

```
$total = null; 
foreach ($members as $owner): 
    if($owner['circle_id'] == $c['id']): // or if($owner['circle_id'] == 1):
        $total = $total + 1;
    endif;
endforeach;
echo $total;
```

This code calculates the number of members within a circle. It matches the members Table id with the current circle id. Its current value is `$c['id'] = 1`