# I need helpless about msq. Multil count in a table

Tags: mysql

```
$sql = SELECT `id`, `email`, `avatar`,`fullname`,
        SUM(result) as sum_result,
        SUM(total) as sum_total,
        COUNT(rank)  as `top_1` where `itq_exam_thread_test`.`rank` = 1, 
        COUNT(rank)  as `top_2` where `itq_exam_thread_test`.`rank` = 2,
        COUNT(rank)  as `top_3` where `itq_exam_thread_test`.`rank` = 3
GROUP BY userid_created
ORDER BY sum_result DESC, sum_rate DESC
LIMIT 0, 100';
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the query, and what language are you doing it?  What about this query is not working?

Comment: Perhaps you'll get some help from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement

Comment: You don't have any  "from tablename" part.

Comment: Sorry $sql = SELECT `id`, `email`, `avatar`,`fullname`,
        SUM(result) as sum_result,
        SUM(total) as sum_total,
        COUNT(rank)  as `top_1` where `itq_exam_thread_test`.`rank` = 1, 
        COUNT(rank)  as `top_2` where `itq_exam_thread_test`.`rank` = 2,
        COUNT(rank)  as `top_3` where `itq_exam_thread_test`.`rank` = 3 FROM  `itq_exam_thread_test`
GROUP BY userid_created
ORDER BY sum_result DESC, sum_rate DESC
LIMIT 0, 100'; But not run