# Count total records by category and subcategory

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by

I have a table where all the employee data with country and city

Main table `Tbl_Emp`

```
ID  Name                       Dept       CountryID        CityID
1   Arun Bikas Das              IT          1               1
2   Abhineet Prakash            IT          1               1
3   Avnish Dhoundiyal           HR          2               5
4   Amit Batra                  HR          3               6
5   Ajay Sethi                  AC          3               6
6   Amarendra Pandey            AC          3               6
7   Abhijit Singh               ADM         1               3
8   Anil Kumar                  ADM         1               4
9   Mahesh Venu                 MAR         1               7
10  Mohamed Rafi                MAR         1               9
```

`Tbl_County` is

```
C_ID    Country
1       India
2       USA
3       UK
```

`tbl_city` is

```
C_ID    City      CountryID
1       Delhi       1
2       Delhi       1
3       Mumbai      1
4       Nagpur      1
5       NewYork     2
6       Caneda      3
7       Jaipur      1
9       Panjab      1
```

I want to select employees count by county:

```
 Country    Employees
 -------    ---------
 India          6 
 USA            1 
 UK             3
```

, and same for the  city:

```
City      Employees
-------   ---------
Delhi           2 
Mumbai          1 
NewYork         1 
Canada          3 
Nagpur          1 
Jaipur          1 
Panjab          1
```

Comment: Kindly post your expected result in tabular form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use count and group by at the same select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement)

Comment: Join the both tables and then select count(id),country and use a group by

Comment: Can you please share with us sample output ?

Comment: try this select table1.Country,count(*) as TotalCount from Tbl_County table1
inner join Tbl_Emp table2
on table1.C_id=table2.countryid
group by table1.country

SELECT table2.City
 ,Count(*) AS TotalCount
FROM Tbl_Emp AS table1
INNER JOIN Tbl_City AS table2 ON table1.City_ID = table2.C_ID
GROUP BY table2.Country

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Country Count:

```
select 
min(c.Country),
count(e.CountryID) as Employees
from 
Tbl_Emp e
join Tbl_County c on e.CountryID = c.c_id
group by e.CountryID
```

For city count:

```
select 
min(c.city),
count(e.CityID) as Employees
from 
Tbl_Emp e
join tbl_city c on e.CityID = c.c_id
group by e.CityID
```

This can be an other solution:

```
select 
    c.Country,
    e.Employees
from (
    select
        CountryID, count(CountryID) as Employees
    from Tbl_Emp
    group by CountryID
) as e  
join Tbl_County c on e.CountryID = c.c_id


select 
    c.city,
    e.Employees
from (
    select
        CityID, count(CityID) as Employees
    from Tbl_Emp
    group by CityID
) as e
join tbl_city c on e.CityID = c.c_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the same for city.  Please do a little more searching before posting, this is a very common thing to do and one that you should have found numerous examples on.  Doing so will help reduce the number of low quality questions being posted.

```
SELECT C.Country, COUNT(*) AS CountryCount
FROM Tbl_Emp E
INNER JOIN TblCounty C
    ON E.CountryID = C.C_ID
GROUP BY C.Country
```

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL `COUNT(*)` :**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

The `COUNT(*)` function returns the number of records in a table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;
```

Following query will give you count based on country :

```
SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Count, Tbl_Country.Country
FROM            Tbl_Country INNER JOIN
                         Tbl_Emp ON Tbl_Country.C_ID = Tbl_Emp.CountryId
GROUP BY Tbl_Country.Country
```

Give a try for City query ,syntax same as above