# SQL Query to identify customers who are at more than one site

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with some SQL query here. I want to select customers are in more than one site Example **peter >> site1 peter >> site2 peter site3** please i have tried with many query but i thing is not correct i need something more logical to do that in oracle sql plus.

```
SQL> select * from HHCCUSTOMERS;

   OID O_CNAME           CID O_SITE  O_BOOKDAT    DEPOSIT    PAYMENT
```

---

```
  1220 tess              120 site3   10-DEC-15        500       1500
  1240 hilda             140 site3   30-JAN-16        300       1500
  1250 isla              150 site2   04-JAN-16        750       1000
  1260 hilda             160 site1   05-FEB-16        800       2000
  1280 maija             180 site3   20-NOV-15        650       1500
  1290 iris              190 site3   10-DEC-15        600       1500
  1200 tess              120 site3   10-DEC-15        500       1500
  1202 hilda             140 site2   30-JAN-16        300       1500
  1203 louise            130 site1   20-NOV-15        600       1000
```

9 rows selected.
**I used this query**

```
 select o_cname,oid,o_site,c_type,c_facility
      from HHCCUSTOMERS
      inner join HHCPARK
      on HHCPARK.cid=HHCCUSTOMERS.cid
      where o_cname='louise' or o_cname='hilda';

O_CNAME           OID O_SITE  C_TYPE     C_FACILITY
---------- ---------- ------- ---------- ----------
louise           1203 site1   bronze     semifurnis
hilda            1240 site3   silver     digitalvan
hilda            1202 site3   silver     digitalvan
hilda            1260 site1   gold       customize
```

Comment: SQL Plus is presumably Oracle, so you should tag the question as Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the customers, then you can do:

```
select c.o_cname
from hhcustomers c
group by c.o_cname
having min(o_site) <> max(o_site);
```

An alternative is:

```
having count(distinct o_site) > 1
```

`count(distinct)` incurs extra overhead, so `min()`/`max()` often has slightly better performance.

If you want the details information, then one method is analytic functions:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             count(distinct o_site) over (partition by o_cname) as numsites
      from hhcustomers c
     ) c
where numsites > 1;
```

Or, an alternative that doesn't directly count the sites uses `exists`:

```
select c.*
from hhcustomers c
where exists (select 1
              from hhcustomers c2
              where c2.o_cname = c.o_cname and c2.o_site <> c.o_site
             );
```

Comment: I did this it worked `select HHCCUSTOMERS.o_cname
from HHCCUSTOMERS
group by HHCCUSTOMERS.o_cname
having count(distinct o_site) > 1;`

Comment: @PeterValentine . . . An expression that selects all the columns from `c`.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want to use `count(.)` and `group by`; something like

```
SELECT O_CNAME, COUNT(O_SITE) AS C FROM HHCCUSTOMERS WHERE C > 1 GROUP BY O_CNAME
```

Note: didn't check this query.

Comment: It is wrong. You can't use a column of an aggregate function in the same query.

Comment: I just did this `SELECT o_cname COUNT(o_site) AS o_cname FROM HHCCUSTOMERS WHERE o_cname > 1 GROUP BY o_cname;` and get this error ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think you can; reference on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2722426/4433386

Comment: @PeterValentine: `COUNT(o_site) AS o_cname` is a bad idea, since you already have a column clalled `o_cname`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
select o_cname, count(*)
  from HHCCUSTOMERS
       inner join HHCPARK
           on HHCPARK.cid=HHCCUSTOMERS.cid
  where o_cname='louise' or o_cname='hilda'
  GROUP BY o_cname
  HAVING count(*)>1;
```

If you leave the where clause it will check on for `louise` or `hilda` if you take the where out it will show everyone who is in more then one place at same time.

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function