# SQL query, count users per month (datetime)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, count

I have a SQL table that i would like to change to the following format:

[image]

I already have that table, but I wasn't able to make it count the users from another table and insert them into the column.

Comment: When you say you "weren't able", what do you mean? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  Something else?

Comment: I think you should (have) look(ed) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you instead of table use view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_CountUsersPerMonth 
AS

SELECT YEAR(SignUpTime) as [Year],
        DATENAME(month,SignUpTime) AS [MonthName],
        COUNT(UserID) AS [CountUsers] 
FROM Tbl_Users 
GROUP BY YEAR(SignUpTime), DATENAME(month,SignUpTime))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it if you are using tSQL, but what about same months in different years?

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  DATENAME(month,SignUpTime) AS [MonthName],
       COUNT(UserID) AS [CountUsers] 
FROM Tbl_Users 
GROUP BY DATENAME(month,SignUpTime))

UPDATE A 
SET A.[CountUsers]=B.[CountUsers]
FROM Tbl_CountUsersPerMonth AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    CTE AS B ON A.[MonthName]=B.[MonthName]
```

Comment: my Database is SQL Server.