# Group by and counting not returning what I expect

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I Have this table where I need to know how many albums an artist has churned during his/her career, I'll post only one artist for brevity's sake.

```
"artist_ID" "song_ID" "album_ID" "touring"
"57"      "98"       "48"      "No"        
"57"      "99"       "48"      "No"        
"57"      "100"      "48"      "Sí"        
"57"      "101"      "48"      "No"        
"57"      "102"      "48"      "No"        
"57"      "103"      "48"      "No"        
"57"      "104"      "48"      "No"        
"57"      "105"      "48"      "No"        
"57"      "106"      "48"      "No"        
"57"      "279"      "163"     "No"        
"57"      "280"      "163"     "No"        
"57"      "281"      "163"     "No"        
"57"      "380"      "241"     "No"        
"57"      "381"      "241"     "No"
```

Then to get the data I go by this:

```
SELECT artist_ID,
    count(*) AS churned_albums
FROM relation
GROUP BY group_ID,
    album_ID;
```

And I expect the following data:

```
"artist_ID" "churned_albums"           
"57"      "3"
```

But alas, I get this:

```
"artist_ID" "churned_albums"
"57"      "9"             
"57"      "3"             
"57"      "2"
```

It's counting every song for every album and I don't know how to tell MySQL to ignore the darn songs and just count albums. I also tried to `count(artist_ID)` instead of `count(*)` and several other permutations, but nothing seems to work.

This question is closely related to [How to use count and group by at the same select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement) and [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns) but they did not help. :(

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: There is no "group_id" column in your data.

Comment: Why select one thing but group by another thing??

Comment: @Tibrogargan woops! Forgot to edit those. The table is in another language and I forgot to translate those strings. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a **sqlfiddle** for visualization of your desired query. Have a look here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1372/2

The query I have used:

```
select group_id, count(distinct album_id) AS churned_albums
from relations
group by group_id;
```

Comment: I did the same query on sqlfiddle but you were faster :P

Comment: Thank you Fuzzy and arsho! Also thanks for letting me know about SQL Fiddle, it'll come in handy for future questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count(distinct album_id)` to count the # of unique albums per `group_id`

```
select group_id,
    count(distinct album_id) as churned_albums
from relation
group by group_id
```