# MySQL COUNT() GROUP BY doesn't work

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have a problem in counting by **MySQL** in a `GROUP BY`
This is the query that does not return the desired result.

```
SELECT COUNT(bagno)
FROM disposizione_assegnazione_pezze
JOIN pezze 
  ON pezza = id
WHERE id_prodotto_tessuto = 12096
  AND id_collezione = 11 
  AND id_stagione = 22 
  AND id_tema = 1
GROUP BY bagno
```

The result of the count is **3**

This is the `pezza` table and its primary key is `id`

[image: Table pezza with results]

This is the table `disposizione_assegnazione_pezze` that has the `pezza` column which refers to the previous table

[image: Table disposizione_assegnazione_pezze]

Why does not return **1** as a result my query?

---

### Question of the problem

I want to count how many different `bagno` are there

Comment: Im confussed what is your current result and your desire result?

Comment: if you're trying to query 2 tables, then you need to select both tables.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The result that should return is 1

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: i.e.: `FROM disposizione_assegnazione_pezze, table2` as an addendum to my first comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- But the two tables can be joined using the key `pezza` -> `id`

Comment: I think `COUNT` should be `3` not `1` but put the data as text so we can test it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've updated the example posted the query result is 3, but I expect 1.Because I want to count how many times `bagno` there differently, In this case 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use count and group by at the same select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I dont think you need `GROUP BY`, instead use `DISTINCT`

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT bagno)
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/IWUB36816)**

Check your query without agregatted function `COUNT/GROUP BY`

[image]

As you can see `bagno = 55` appear three times, that is why when you `group by bagno` and count get 3.

Comment: So it works, but I do not understand why. If I use the `GROUP BY` I group all results to have them different, in my case it will return only one result, so if you should count with `COUNT` function I think should be corrected.

Comment: Maybe if you explain what are those fields, or put a bigger example I can give you more detail.

Comment: Check my edit explanation. That is exactly what `DISTINCT` does

Comment: Works great, however, Why if I make a `GROUP BY` and `SELECT *` result only one line? Taking a `COUNT (*)` should not return **1** as a result? Example: http://rextester.com/KNOBO9612

Comment: Samething, the only difference is `COUNT(*)` count the number of row not matter what values are there, `COUNT(bagno)` only count rows where `bagno IS NOT NULL` so ignore null rows.