# MS SQL count AS to new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Good day

I have problem with my table and counting

```
TABLE1
COLUMN1       COLUMN2
3              jjd
5              jd
3              jjd
4              kg 
5              jd
48             gjh
446            djj
…               …
```

I need

```
TABLE1 
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
3         jj         2
5         jd         2
4         kg         1
48        gjh        1
446       djj        1
...        ...       …
```

Iam doing but not working well.

```
SELECT * , COUNT(Column1) as column3 FROM TABLE1
```

Thanks for help withh my counting

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Suggestion: first read the error messages received, second post those message when asking for help. The error message pretty much tells you how to resolve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use count and group by at the same select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Try by using group by

```
    SELECT COLUMN1 , 
       COLUMN2 ,
       COUNT(Column1) As COLUMN3 FROM cte_TABLE1
    Group by COLUMN1 ,COLUMN2 
    Order by COLUMN1
```

By using Window function

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1 , 
       COLUMN2 ,
       COUNT(Column1)OVER(Partition by COLUMN1,COLUMN2 ORder by COLUMN1 ) As COLUMN3 FROM cte_TABLE1
```

Result

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 column3
-----------------------
3       jjd      2
4       kg       1
5       jd       2
48      gjh      1
446     djj      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` with `DESC` to put them in `COUNT` total order.

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COUNT(Column1) AS COLUMN3 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2
ORDER BY COUNT(Column1) DESC
```

Output

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
5       jd      2
3       jjd     2
4       kg      1
446     djj     1
48      gjh     1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89f49/4/0

Answer (score 0):

Using OVER we can achieve it easily

```
SELECT  COLUMN1 , 
       COLUMN2 ,
       COUNT(Column1)OVER(Partition by COLUMN1,COLUMN2 ORder by COLUMN1 ) As COLUMN3 FROM cte_TABLE1
Group By COLUMN1,COLUMN2
```