# MySQL display a count of rows for 2 Group Bys

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry in advance, I'm not exactly sure how to explain this but I am trying to do this:

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
id | make | model

1 | iphone | iphone 7
2 | iphone | iphone 8
3 | iphone | iphone 10
4 | samsung | galaxy note 5
5 | samsung | galaxy note 5
6 | samsung | galaxy note 4
7 | iphone | iphone 7
8 | iphone | iphone 7
9 | htc | one
```

I want the results to look like this:

```
htc | one | 1 
iphone | iphone 7 | 3 
samsung | galaxy note 5 | 2
```

So essentially I only want the count for the most rows for each model while grouping both the make and the model.

Hope that makes some sort of sense to someone.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: this should get you what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use count and group by at the same select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement)

Comment: @herrbischoff no, it's not.

Comment: There are only 2 iphone 7s

Comment: oh shoot sorry my bad there was a typo the first record should of been iphone 7.

Comment: Thank you everyone who gave some thought and input into this much appreciated!

Comment: If any of the answers below has solved/helped you to solve your problem,kindly mark it as an answer and/or upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to display the `model` with Maximum count for each `make`.

Following query will just do that:

```
select make,model,count(*) as cnt
from phones p1
group by make,model
having cnt =  (select max(p2.cnt) 
               from 
                   (select make,model,count(*) as cnt
                          from phones
                          group by make,model
                   )p2
                where p2.make = p1.make                
               )
 ;
```

[Click here for updated DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c76256/77/0)

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Strawberry Can you please explain?

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, i come to know that. Thank you for pointing it out. Although I've updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's ok - although I'm not sure that it scales so well.

Answer (score 1):

Do some tricks with mysql functions, you can use `substring_index` and `group_concat`:

```
select 
  `make`,
  substring_index(group_concat(`model` order by cnt desc), ',', 1) `model`,
  max(cnt) max_count
from (
  select `make`, `model`, count(1) cnt
  from yourtable
  group by `make`, `model`) t
group by `make`
```

See [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0b732/4) in SQLFiddle.

Some explaination:

- Subquery `t` will query count of each group `make`, `model`;
- `group_concat(model order by cnt desc)` with `group by make` will let all `model` be concated with separator `,` and `order by cnt desc`;
- `substring_index` is a function which can split string with specified separator and return sub-string according to the index we passed.

All these functions you can check mysql official documents to learn more information.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably after something like this:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT make
            , model
            , COUNT(*) total 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY make
            , model
     ) a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT make
            , MAX(total) total 
         FROM 
            ( SELECT make
                   , model
                   , COUNT(*) total 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP 
                  BY make
                 , model
          ) x 
       GROUP 
            BY make
     ) b
    ON b.make = a.make 
   AND b.total = a.total;
```

Comment: This one did the trick.  You are a life saver Strawberry thank you!  I was no where close to getting this one lol.