# count and groupby together in one query

Tags: php, sql

The following query is fetching some product info on a page which is fine, but I also want to show the number of the product that it occurs as a text, however, I used `groupby` but I also want to use `count` on `pro_id`.

```
 "SELECT * FROM cart  WHERE session_id='" . $_SESSION['session'] . "' GROUP BY 
    pro_id  "
```

Comment: can you show your table structure?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement

Comment: table structre is like  --- cart_id (pk)--- pro_id(fk)---- pro_name---pro_price---pro_image  @pravindot17

Comment: did you tried `$query = "SELECT pro_id, count(*) as prod_count FROM cart  WHERE session_id='" . $_SESSION['session'] . "' GROUP BY pro_id  "`?

Comment: yes it worked like this thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query won't work. Try like this;

```
 "SELECT pro_id,count(*) FROM cart  WHERE session_id='" . $_SESSION['session'] . "' GROUP BY 
  pro_id  "
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
"SELECT pro_id,count(pro_id) FROM cart  WHERE session_id='" . $_SESSION['session'] . "' GROUP BY pro_id  "
```