# how to count subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this query :

```
Select
  DATE_FORMAT(calls.call_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d") as `groupdate`
from
  calls
WHERE calls.job_id =1
group by DATE_FORMAT(calls.call_datetime,
"%Y-%m-%d")
```

with return :

> groupdate
>
> 2018-07-06
>
> 2018-07-06

there are 2 rows. how do I count the above query so that the result becomes '2' with one row ?

what i want is:

> Result
>
> 2

thanks, please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use count and group by at the same select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement)

Comment: @Alexander - No, That is not the same question.  True, the second best answer to that question is correct for _this_ question, but it is wrong for _that_ question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simple would be to use

```
Select
  COUNT(*) as Result
from
  calls
WHERE calls.job_id =1
group by DATE_FORMAT(calls.call_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

or a delivered table approach

```
SELECT
 COUNT(*) as Result
FROM (
  Select
    DATE_FORMAT(calls.call_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d") as `groupdate`
  from
    calls
  WHERE calls.job_id =1 
  group by DATE_FORMAT(calls.call_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d")
) AS a
```

Both queries should return the same expected result you want.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Select
  Count(DATE_FORMAT(calls.call_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d")) as `groupdate`
from
  calls
WHERE calls.job_id =1
group by DATE_FORMAT(calls.call_datetime,
"%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use count()

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(calls.call_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d") as groupdate , count(*)
from calls 
WHERE calls.job_id =1 
group by DATE_FORMAT(calls.call_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous.  Is the desired answer "2" because there are 2 rows for 1 date?  What if there were more than one date?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calls WHERE ...; -- delivers "2"

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calls WHERE ...; GROUP BY DATE(datetime) -- also delivers "2"

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(call_datetime)) FROM calls WHERE ...; -- delivers "1"
```