# How to add count(*) results in total?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, count

I don't know how to add all count(*) results. I mean, if i have red publisher, who has got 2 books, and blue publisher with 6 books. I have to get how many books have each one and how many books are in total. The first part I've done. How to do the second one? My code:

```
 SELECT Publisher, count(*) AS ct 
 FROM  Stud.Book 
 Group by Publisher;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use count and group by at the same select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement)

Answer (score 2):

That's what `rollup` is for:

```
SELECT Publisher, count(*) AS ct 
FROM  Stud.Book 
Group by rollup(Publisher);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use grouping sets for that:

```
SELECT publisher, count(*) AS ct 
FROM  stud.book 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((publisher), ());
```