# sql code to create a table for sum of number

Tags: sql

[image]

using this table, and
I want to make the sql result is:

- name     total score
- SAM   245
- MARY   120
- JOHN    205

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use count and group by at the same select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement)

Comment: sorry, I updated a new example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `group` and `sum`

```
select name, sum(score) as total
from table
group by name
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 